# CircleCI config.yml for nodejs

Tags: node.js, docker, continuous-integration, yaml, circleci

```
version: 2
  jobs:
    test:
      docker:
        - image: circleci/node:12.16
      steps:
        - checkout
        - run: echo "Running tests"
        - run: npm install
        - run: npm test
      build:
        docker:
          - image: circleci/node:12.16
        steps:
          - checkout
          - run: echo "build project"
          - npm install
          - npm run build
workflows:
  version: 2
    test_build:
      jobs:
        - test
        - build:
          requires:
            - test
```

The above YAML is my config.yml for CircleCI, but I get this error

```
Config does not conform to schema: {:workflows {:test_and_build {:jobs [nil {:build (not (map? nil)), :requires (not (map? a-clojure.lang.LazySeq))}]}}}
```

Another observation is if I run the jobs in parallel, they run without any errors.
That is if I remove the requires: - test as shown below

```
workflows:
  version: 2
    test_build:
      jobs:
        - test
        - build
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this one and it worked. The problem with the previous one seemed to be related to versioning. CircleCI cloud 2.1 and CircleCI server 2. Also, I decided to use the node orbs this time.

```
version: 2.1

orbs:
  node: circleci/node@3.0.1

jobs:
  build:
    working_directory: ~/backend_api
    executor: node/default
    steps:
      - checkout
      - node/install-npm
      - node/install-packages:
          app-dir: ~/backend_api
          cache-path: node_modules
          override-ci-command: npm i
      - persist_to_workspace:
          root: .
          paths:
            - .

  test:
    docker:
      - image: cimg/node:current
    steps:
      - attach_workspace:
          at: .
      - run:
          name: Test
          command: npm test

workflows:
  version: 2
  build_and_test:
    jobs:
      - build
      - test:
          requires:
            - build
```

Answer (score 1):

`build` is a job, just like `test`, and should be indented the same way it is:

```
version: 2
  jobs:
    test:
      docker:
        - image: circleci/node:12.16
      steps:
        - checkout
        - run: echo "Running tests"
        - run: npm install
        - run: npm test
    build:
      docker:
        - image: circleci/node:12.16
      steps:
        - checkout
        - run: echo "build project"
        - npm install
        - npm run build

workflows:
  version: 2
    test_build:
      jobs:
        - test
        - build:
          requires:
            - test
```